# Spring mongo repository crud combined with criteria

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, jpa-2.0

I have the following two repository classes in my project.

```
@Repository
public interface AuditRepository extends MongoRepository<AuditEntity, String> {
}
```

And also one that has more complex queries.

```
@Service
public class AuditCriteriaRepository {

  private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  public AuditCriteriaRepository(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate){
    this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
  }


  public List<AuditEntity > getAuditEntitiesByStatus(AuditStatus auditStatus, Instant instant){
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("status")
        .is(auditStatus)
    ).addCriteria(Criteria.where("createdAt").lt(instant));
    return mongoTemplate.find(query, AuditEntity.class);
  }
}
```

The problem I have now is they are Autowired as separate classes and I would prefer if I could combine the two as one repository class so I can have the default crud options and build criteria ones also.

Any advice / tips on how to do that?

Comment: One suggestion would be to create custom queries (using `@Query` annotation) in `AuditRepository` itself. Is there a real need to use MongoTemplate from the second repository? Otherwise, you have to continue with separate repository classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to autowire two different classes, you can extend your repository with your custom calls.

For example, let's say you created an additional interface called `AuditCriteriaRepository`, containing:

```java
public interface AuditCriteriaRepository {
    List<AuditEvent> getAuditEntitiesByStatus(AuditStatus auditStatus, Instant instant);
}
```

After that, you can extend your `AuditRepository` with the new interface:

```java
public interface AuditRepository extends MongoRepository<AuditEntity, String>, AuditCriteriaRepository {
}
```

Additionally, you'll have to implement `AuditCriteriaRepository` using the code you wrote:

```java
public class AuditCriteriaRepositoryImpl implements AuditCriteriaRepository {

  private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  public AuditCriteriaRepository(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate){
    this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
  }


  public List<AuditEntity > getAuditEntitiesByStatus(AuditStatus auditStatus, Instant instant){
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("status")
        .is(auditStatus)
    ).addCriteria(Criteria.where("createdAt").lt(instant));
    return mongoTemplate.find(query, AuditEntity.class);
  }
}
```

Now you can autowire `AuditRepository` and call `getAuditEntitiesByStatus()` directly on the repository itself.

Comment: what classes would need annotations? just the @repository on AuditRepository interface?

Comment: I don't think you need any annotation at all.

Comment: you are correct you dont need it.  Great answer thanks

Comment: Hi all, i notice that this method getAuditEntitiesByStatus(), cannot be named to any arbitrary name, otherwise during application boot up, there will be error. Is there a way for me to give it an arbitrary name?

Comment: As @Bruce, I run into a PropertyReferenceException: No property {method name} found for type {Class}! The custom repository behaves as a Spring Data MongoRepository and expect methods to match a certain name pattern so it can translate to queries. Naming it "find" or "get" or whatever other name doesn't work for me.

Comment: @luso That's weird, I'm pretty sure I tested it back then, can't confirm it now. Maybe the repository implementation isn't recognized. It's important that the name of the class (eg. `AuditCriteriaRepositoryImpl`) is the same as the interface + `Impl`. Otherwise, the implementation is not picked up by Spring. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) for more info.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I use to name the interfaces IWhateverInterfaceName and nothing in the implementation. First time I read about this having to be in the other way around! I'll give it another try. Thanks! @g00glen00b

Comment: As described in [Spring Data Jpa Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/custom-implementations.html#repositories.configuration) - "*The repository infrastructure tries to autodetect custom implementation fragments by scanning for classes below the package in which it found a repository. These classes need to follow the naming convention of appending a postfix defaulting to Impl.*"
So no annotations are needed. Just place the *Impl class in a sub-package of the one where the custom repository interface resides.